# How to use the progress bar?

Tags: android

In my application, onclick of menu it is taking time to load the next activity. So in between the screen is black for sometime.What should I do? Shall I add a progress bar? .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need: [Async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
It will create a separate thread to display the loader